# Creating the dual of a graph - planar face traversal - vtkBoostGraphAdapter

Tags: boost, vtk, planar-graph

I'm trying to write an algorithm which creates the dual of a graph. To check whether the graph is planar or not I use the *Boyer-Myrvold planarity test* (Boost implementation) through the `vtkBoostGraphAdapter`. That works fine (only on `vtkUndirectedGraph`-s but that's OK for now).
(boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/graph/doc/boyer_myrvold.html)

To create the dual I need to traverse the faces of the planar graph for which I also have a Boost tool called the `planar_face_traversal_visitor`.
(boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_face_traversal.html)
There's a guy, Aaron Windsor who implemented the appropriate visitor class that is able to create the dual of a graph in Boost.
(https://github.com/aaw/boost_planar_graph_dual)
That also works fine using only Boost but I'd like to adapt this feature as well using `vtkBoostGraphAdapter`.

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/g0Mtw6Ph

These are my errors:

- /usr/local/boost_1_56_0/boost/property_map/**property_map.hpp**:302:19:
  No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const
  boost::iterator_property_map,
  std::__1::allocator > >
  *>, boost::vtkGraphIndexMap, std::__1::map, std::__1::allocator > >, std::__1::map, std::__1::allocator > > &>'
- /usr/local/boost_1_56_0/boost/property_map/**property_map.hpp**:309:5: No
  viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const
  boost::iterator_property_map,
  std::__1::allocator > >
  *>, boost::vtkGraphIndexMap, std::__1::map, std::__1::allocator > >, std::__1::map, std::__1::allocator > > &>'
- /usr/local/boost_1_56_0/boost/property_map/**property_map.hpp**:302:19:
  No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const
  boost::iterator_property_map, std::__1::allocator > *>,
  boost::vtkGraphIndexMap, std::__1::set, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::set, std::__1::allocator > &>'
- /usr/local/boost_1_56_0/boost/property_map/**property_map.hpp**:309:5: No
  viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const
  boost::iterator_property_map, std::__1::allocator > *>,
  boost::vtkGraphIndexMap, std::__1::set, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::set, std::__1::allocator > &>'
- /usr/local/boost_1_56_0/boost/**planar_dual.hpp**:38:38: No viable
  overloaded operator[] for type 'edge_to_face_map_t' (aka
  'iterator_property_map')

I've been dealing with this, reading the source code really deep and trying a couple of things in the past few days but I can't really figure out what the problem is. Is the `vtkBoostGraphAdapter` properly prepared for this kind of usage?

Any kind of help appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Szilard

Comment: Please link to your relevant discussion http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.vtk.user/74535 on the vtkusers list

Comment: VTK Users: http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Creating-the-dual-of-a-graph-planar-face-traversal-vtkBoostGraphAdapter-tt5729055.html

VTK Dev: http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Re-vtkusers-Creating-the-dual-of-a-graph-planar-face-traversal-vtkBoostGraphAdapter-tt5729058.html